# Cannot insert NULL into a non-identity column in Entity Framework. Funny thing... it's not null?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I have a SalesOrder table with columns for ID and OrderID. ID is an auto-generated int. OrderID is a non-nullable string with a max length of 20, and we use it to store the customer's order number for reference.

After adding my new SalesOrder and calling SaveChanges, I get the following error:

*Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderID', table 'SalesOrder'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.*

Problem is, the object that I'm saving actually ***does*** have an OrderID! It's almost like it's trying to save the entity first before it saves all the values. Is this how EF handles things?

My setup is EF4.1, using an EDMX model-first approach. StoreGeneratedPattern is set to None. Default Value is currently set to (None) but I've tried various values. Entity Key is False, since it's not part of the key. I've also tried deleting the SalesOrder entity and regenerating it from the database.

Comment: can you provide the code where you do the insert? before the 'SaveChanges()' ?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to see your code...I had similar problems when filling objects in a loop then saving them with savechanges. I thought all the fields were populated, but they were not.

I'd have to see your code that executes before the save changes before I can offer anything really helpful.

If your problem is like mine and you are calling savechanges after using an iterator to populate your objects, then you can find the bad data by moving savechanges into the iterator so that it is called with each iteration...but this is all hypothetical guesswork without seeing your code...